LinkedIn Marketing API - Programmatically retrieve Authorization Code in 3-legged flow
For LinkedIn Marketing API docs, only member authentication flow (3-legged flow) is supported, which requires the user to actually login into LinkedIn through a browser screen in order to retrieve the authorization code. Only with this authorization code, we can request for an Access Token, with which I can perform API requests. But there is no way specified in the docs, on how to retrieve this authorization code programmatically.
Currently, I am able to retrieve the auth code from browser login. Also the marketing APIs doesn't support client-credential flow (2-legged flow) which can be used to directly get the access token without auth code. So I am stuck with the 3-legged flow for marketing APIs.
I am also using an Organization account instead of standard individual account.
Is there any way to retrieve the auth code programmatically, specifically for Organization accounts?
